# Does RxJava map() return value on assignment?

Tags: java, rx-java

I've got a code, like this:

```
Observable
    .create(...)
    .map(client -> localClient = client)
    .flatMap(client -> ...);
```

Does it just assigns "client" to some local instance "localClient" and returns it? Or i should explicitly write

```
Observable
    .create(...)
    .map(client -> {localClient = client; return client; })
    .flatMap(client -> ...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet works as you want it to, the result of the assignment is returned so will become the `client` that is passed through the rest of your Rx chain.